# Prediction/delay forcasting using Machine Learning?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-mining, weka, data-analysis

I have a set of data for the past 5 years. Approx 7000 rows of data with features that are binary {yes/no} or are multi-classed {product A, B, C} A total of about 20+ features.

I am trying to make a program (or one time analysis project) to determine (predict) the product shipdate(shipping delay days) based on this historical data. I have 2 columns that indicate when a product was planned to be shipped and another column of when it was *actually* shipped! Currently.

I'm wondering how I can make a prediction program that determines based on the historic data when new data input of a product will expect to ship. I don't care about a getting a specific date but even just a program that can tell me number of delay days to add...

I took an ML class a while back and I wasn't sure how to start something like this. Any advice? Plus the closest thing to this I can think of is an image recognition assignment using NN. but that was too easy here I have to deal with a date instead of pixel white/black.... I used Matlab back in the day (I still know how to use it) but I just downloaded Weka data mining tool.

I was thinking of a neural network but I'm not sure how to set it up to have my program give me a the expected delay time (# of days/month) from the inputed ship date.

Basically,

I want to input (size = 5, prod = A, ....,expected ship date = jan 1st)

and the program returns the number of days to add as a delay onto my expected ship date given the historical trends...

Would appreciate any any help on how start something like this the correct/easiest/best way... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that your data is so discrete, I would suggest a decision tree. You can use Weka :)

Comment: Thanks @Ansari, Anony-Mousse. I tried playing around with Weka a bit. The part that is really confusing me is how to deal with the "date" aspect. Since every part of my data is discrete and I have this date part I'm trying to predict. How do I treat it? do i look at it as a continuous variable, discrete... That's the biggest thing that's confusing me. Do you happen to have anything I should read up on when working with a time factor? thx again

Comment: If you think the date itself plays no role in determining the delay, then I would just work with the delay (number of days) and not the date. If you think the date does influence things, you can extract things like day of the week, month, week number, etc. from the date and treat them as variables to build the tree on or regress. If you build a tree it should figure out if they're important or not.

Comment: Thanks @Ansari I'll look into decision trees. The date doesn't matter.  And I have converted the date to day of year. You wouldn't happen to have any suggested reading (papers, tutorials) for some one who hasn't explicity worked with decision trees? I'm researching them now and will try my best to use Weka. I'm also not familiar with how to use Weka experimenter to predict..

Comment: Day of year may be too fine a parameter to split on. I suggest day of month or day of week additionally, just to see if there is any signal in any of those variables. Decision trees are fairly old and stable by now, so you can find lots online. Of course there are traditional machine learning textbooks as well that you can read (Mitchell, Russell/Norvig, etc.). As for Weka, it's been a while so I don't remember exactly, but it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you use weka, then get your input/label data into the [arff](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) format and then you try out all the different [regressors](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/functions/package-summary.html) (this is a regression problem after all). To avoid having to do too much programming quite yet (if you are just in an exploratory phase), use the [weka experimenter](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/course_archive/2006-07/W/4412/doc/weka/ExperimenterTutorial-3.5.5.pdf) which has a GUI for trying out a whole bunch of regressors on your dataset.

Then when you find one that does something expected and you want to do some more data analysis using MATLAB, then you can use a [weka/matlab interface](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21204-matlab-weka-interface).

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, that part that is really confusing me is how to deal with the "date" aspect. Since every part of my data is discrete...I have this date part I'm trying to predict. How do I treat it? do i look at it as a continuous variable, discrete... That's the biggest thing that's confusing to me. Do you happen to have anything I should read up on when working with a time factor? thx again

Comment: In your case, I think it would be a discrete (integer) value (but in general, it could be continuous). In your case, you said you wanted to know the date it ships, create your target vector (the thing you're trying to predict) by computing number of days between the expected ship date and the actual ship date. Then the regressor you build will tell you how many days to tack on to the end of the expected ship date.